# Problem with orderby

Tags: taxonomy, order

I am querying the terms in a custom taxonomy i have with the following code:

```
<?php 
    $term_id = 2;
    $taxonomy_name = 'rete';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

      $args         = array(
      'child_of' => $termchildren->term_id,
      'orderby'  => 'id',
      'order'    => 'DESC'
      );

 $term = get_terms($taxonomy_name, $args);

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li><a class="uno">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';



    }
    echo '</ul>';


  ?>
```

Works fine but do not order! The problem i have is that i would like to order it by title-order or something similar.

Can anyone suggest what i need to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the orderby from "title" to "name". [See here for a list of acceptable arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Possible_Arguments).

Comment: I've tried but do no works